# Count all cases with one MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

I'd like to return a total count, then also return the results of the where statement.

```
SELECT count(cases) 
from `table`
WHERE stats = 'open'.
```

The above will count where stats = open, I need to do a count first of all cases, then also do a count of the where statement. Something like:

```
SELECT count(cases)
from `table`
\\return count of all cases
where stats= count(open).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM( stats = 'open' ),  -- count of all stats open
       SUM( stats <> 'open' )  -- count of all stats NOT open
from `table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
SELECT COUNT(cases)
FROM `table`
HAVING stats = COUNT(open)
```